# Change ptrace_scope temporarily for a specific user

Tags: security, sudo, ptrace

[`ptrace_scope`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/Roadmap/KernelHardening#ptrace_Protection) is a sysctl value (`/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`) that prevents the use of `ptrace` on non-child processes when set to 1.  This is generally considered good security practice.

Unfortunately, being able to ptrace a process as a developer (and attach to a running process, so not a child process) is very useful.  Using `sudo` with the `CAP_SYS_PTRACE` capability allows one to attach to *any* running process, not just processes owned by the user.  On a shared dev box, it might not be desirable to allow `ptrace` via `sudo` for all processes, as that essentially allows arbitrary code to be run as any user.

What I would like to do is allow a user to sudo (or otherwise require authentication) to ptrace a non-child process, but not to allow them to ptrace arbitrary processes.  Essentially allowing them to change `ptrace_scope` for themselves on a temporary, authentication guarded basis.

Is this possible?

Comment: How are you grouping what they can or can't `ptrace`? Maybe put the devs in containers?

Comment: @user1794469: I guess that Andrew is saying that he wants the developers to be able to trace *processes they own,* even if they aren’t child processes.  (I was confused by the question the first time I read it, too.)

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica': that is correct.  Sorry that it isn't clear

Comment: Linux has no concept for limited time permissions or capabilities and it does not allow permissions on interpreted files. You can not user scripts and have to use either libcap2-bin, capsh without timeout. To get a timeout, I would recommend using the landlock API or the more general libcap one depending on your use case.

Comment: See also https://blog.container-solutions.com/linux-capabilities-in-practice and alike articles how capabilities are stored and used.